# Cannot update sublistfield in Netsuite in .each() method

Tags: netsuite, sublist, suitescript2.0

I am fairly new to Netsuite.
I have got a strange issue and cannot solve it.

I am using WorkFlow with states and have Saved Searches they return the matching items on Sales Order.
I need to update a custom field on each line for the returned items.

I have this in my action script

```
itemSearch.run().each(elem => {
                let lineNum = parseInt(elem.getValue('linesequencenumber'), 10) - 1;
                log.audit({
                    title: 'linesequencenumber',
                    details: {lineNum, type: typeof lineNum}
                });
                newRec.setSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: SO_LN_ITEM_PROCESS,
                    line: lineNum,
                    value: 1
                });
                log.debug({ // this one retrieves the field value correctly but when refresh page after WF finished and existed then the fields are empty.
                    title: 'currValue', details: newRec.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: SO_LN_ITEM_PROCESS,
                        line: lineNum,
                    })
                });
                updatedItemsCnt++;

                return true;
            });
```

It should work and update the fields value. If I use `getSublistValue` just right after the `setSublistValue` method and log it then it shows me the value that I expect.
After the run refresh the page and the field is not updated. It is empty. And here comes the strange thing I do not understand. The following script is working. But it is hardcoded.

```
[0, 4].forEach(line => {
            newRec.setSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: SO_LN_ITEM_PROCESS,
                            line: lineNum,
                            value: 1
                        });
    });
```

If I create the array manually then the fields are updated.
I have tried to push the values into Array and use forEach, for loop to iterate the values through but the fields are still not updated only if I create the array manually.

The log

```
1   View    Debug   currValue   7/10/2020   2:40 pm -System-    1
2   View    Audit   linesequencenumber  7/10/2020   2:40 pm -System-    {"lineNum":4,"type":"number"}
```

The `currValue` is one of the value that logged right after `setSublistValue`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try comiting the line after setting the value?  Not sure if you are doing that outside the shown code or not.

Comment: I am using standard mode and not dynamic mode. Should I use dynamic mode?

Comment: What Script Type is this? What Entry Point event is it?

Comment: Nah, record.setSublistValue is for standard mode only.

Comment: It is a WorkFlow custom action script. The entry point is onAction

Comment: What Trigger Type then for the Workflow/State? Before or After Submit?

Comment: The WorkFlow will be scheduled and using Saved Search. The trigger type on the state is Entry

Comment: I have got it working. But not sure it is the right way to do.
As scriptContext is available I am not keen to load the record but it seems the only way.
So I load the record and update the lines and save it. It works.
Please let me know if it is right however my instinct says no.

Comment: I have done more testing. Once the field is updated an WF goes to next state then it is aware of it. However I use Saved Search to filter items on different criteria in each state and Saved Search cannot see those changes. I am thinking it because the record is not submitted until reaches the end of the WF and Saved Search grabs the un-updated instance of it. However it still does not make sense why it gets updated if I use array. I am thinking to make it simpler.